# Scala avoid Thread sleep for asynchronous test cases

Tags: multithreading, scala, testing, future

I'm writing unit tests for a method that runs a primary function and then logs details about the request asynchronously.

```scala
def someMethod(data: Object): SomeType =
  for {
    result <- someOtherMethod(data).withLogging(logMethod)
  }
```

The method `logMethod` is an async task. In my tests, I want to ensure that the logger is receiving a message, however, the thread completes too soon at times making the test flaky and causing an `Unsatisfied` result sometimes.

Example test case:

```scala
it("logs an error if an upload was attempted with some failure case") {
  val uploadData = someData

  mockSomeCall()

  mockAnotherCall()

  testController.methodWeAreTesting(uploadData).shouldBeRight()

  Thread.sleep(75)

  (stubLogger
    .warn(_: RichMsg, _: Throwable, _: AnyId)(_: () => SourceLocation))
    .verify(where { (msg: RichMsg, _, _, _) =>
      msg.toString.equals(s"Some specific message")
     })
}
```

I'm not enjoying adding a `Thread.sleep` every time I need to ensure that the logger is receiving a specific message. I'd like to be able to possibly wrap the `stubLogger` expectation.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: What testing library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think `promise` is what you need to add in `logMethod`.
As per the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html):

> While futures are defined as a type of read-only placeholder object
>   created for a result which doesn’t yet exist, a promise can be thought
>   of as a writable, single-assignment container, which completes a
>   future. That is, a promise can be used to successfully complete a
>   future with a value (by “completing” the promise) using the success
>   method. Conversely, a promise can also be used to complete a future
>   with an exception, by failing the promise, using the failure method.
>
> A promise p completes the future returned by p.future. This future is
>   specific to the promise p. Depending on the implementation, it may be
>   the case that p.future eq p.

In the tests, once you get back the result, you can compare the result with the message that you are trying to compare.

A sample code is shown below:

```
object Test1 extends App {
  import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

  var promiseMessage: String = _
  val promise = Promise[String] //The promise will hold a string

  //A future tells the System to spawn a new thread and run the code block inside it
  val logMethod =  (elem: String) => Future{
    promise.success(elem)
    elem
  }

  def method(data: String): Future[String] = {
    for {
      result <- logMethod(data)
    } yield result
  }

  val f1 = method("Hi!! I love scala async programming")

  promise completeWith f1
  val promiseFuture = promise.future

  promiseFuture onComplete {
    case Success(value) =>
      promiseMessage = value
      println(promiseMessage)
    case Failure(ex) => println(ex)
  }

  Await.result(promiseFuture, 100 seconds)

  if (promiseMessage == "Hi!! I love scala async programming") println("correct")
}
```

In the code, `promise` is a Promise object which promises a string when the future gets complete. All you need to do is complete the promise with future as shown in:
`promise completeWith f1` and then, add a handler as to what to do when it is successful or failure using `promiseFuture onComplete`.

If you want to check if logging happened you can `await` on the `promiseFuture` or else continue with the further process and when the logging is done, the promise will print that is successful as shown in the code.

Let me know it helps!!